# C++ reading structs by field and writing struct directly to a stream

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, abi

I'm using C++ with visual studio 2008. Say I have a structure like so:

```
    struct StructOfInts
    { 
        int a;
        int b;
        int c; 
    };
```

That's meant to be read and written like so:

```
    void Read( std::istream& is, StructOfInts& myStruct  )
    {
        is.read( (char*)&myStruct.a, sizeof myStruct.a );
        is.read( (char*)&myStruct.b, sizeof myStruct.b );
        is.read( (char*)&myStruct.c, sizeof myStruct.c );
    }
    void Write( std::ostream& os, StructOfInts& myStuct )
    {
        os.write( (char*)&myStruct, sizeof myStruct );
    }
```

Can the above code result in some sort of memory corruption when reading from or writing to a file? By memory corruption, I mean incorrect values being read in. I'm trying to determine the source of a -1.#QNB value that's being read in and am wondering if this could be the cause. 
Also, is there a difference if I pack the structure using pragma pack?

Comment: Any particular reason for not using the >> operator?

Comment: No particular reason. This is just how the (very old) codebase I'm working with is like and this is to maintain consistency.

Comment: I think the problem is in this line: `os.write( (char*)&myStruct, sizeof myStruct );`. Try writing to `ostream` element by element. Because there might be padding if you are on a 64 bit machine as `sizeof(int)` will be 32 bits.

Comment: That's what I was thinking when justin and feralin posted their answers. However, when I compared the size of my structure to the total size of the individual fields of the structure, they were the same.

Comment: okay. What is the value you are trying to read when you get `-1.QNB`

Comment: The structure I'm using is different from the structure in this question, since I just wanted to give an example. 
In my case, it's one (sometimes, two) 32 bit float(s) that's giving me problems. The structure that I'm using contains 17 32-bit floats and 44 32-bit unsigned integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick way to test this case is:

```
static_assert(sizeof(StructOfInts) == (3 * sizeof(int)), "size mismatch");
```

The best way to accomplish this (IMO) is to use a symmetric form: serialize field-by-field and then also deserialize field-by-field.

In short, to rely on the behaviour your implementation uses is to rely on the ABI of the targeted architecture, rather than the standard (BAD). Thus, it could result in 'corruption'.

The size of the structure can vary by ABI, and the size of ints and even their byte order could vary -- resulting in 'corruption'. Padding and alignment is also specified by an ABI.

So fixed width types, explicit endianness, and field by field symmetric serialization will often be what you need.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried the static assertion (good idea btw), and unfortunately (or fortunately) it didn't trigger. Do you think that it means that the reading/writing in my particular case would happen correctly? The problem I'm facing happens VERY inconsistently and might or might not be related to this.

Comment: @k9ty if you're only running on one architecture when reading and writing these files (e.g. windows, 32 bit), then the problem would be elsewhere. your program just tells it to do byte copying of POD, and the sizes agree. if you run it on multiple platforms/architectures, then it is permissable for the serialized representation to differ (i.e. sizeof(int) may not even be the same).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your code *could* result in invalid values being read in, due to possible padding between `struct` fields. Let's use the example of your `struct StructOfInts`, and imagine that the compiler inserts some padding between the fields, like so:

```
byte  | 0 1 2 3 | 4 5     | 6 7 8 9 | 10 11 12 13
value | field a | padding | field b | field c
```

Then when you write the struct to the stream, you could end up with something like

```
byte | 0  1  2  3   | 4   5   | 6  7  8  9   | 10 11 12 13
char | \0 \0 \0 'a' | '?' '?' | \0 \0 \0 'b' | \0 \0 \0 'c'
```

if the fields contained (respectively) the values `(int)'a', (int)'b', (int)'c'`.

Then when you read the values back in, it would look like

```
myStruct->a = int version of \0 \0 \0 'a'
myStruct->b = int version of '?' '?' \0 \0
myStruct->c = int version of \0 'b' \0 \0
```

which is obviously not what you want.

After searching around about `#pragma pack`, it looks like it would help with this case. The compiler would not insert padding (although it *is* implementation defined...), so the values would (most likely) be read and written correctly.

Also, another thing: if you do the writing on one system (computer/OS/compiler) and then read the data in another system, then endianness issues could cause problems as well.